# How to hide column of data from highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a CSV file with this content:

```
Date,Value
2014-01-12,11286,3031
2014-01-13,11994,2115
```

How can I hide the last column (with values `3031` and `2115`) from appearing in my HighChart?

Comment: How you parse your data?

Comment: in one line (.csv)
Date: 2014-01-12, 2014-01-13
Value: 11286, 11994
3 column: 3031, 2115 <- how hide ?

Comment: Please supply us information how to parse, I mean convert CSV to Javascript?